# Representation of permutation subgroup

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

Consider $I_g$ the automorphism $x \mapsto I_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$.

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $P(H)$ the permutations of $H$. Is the application $I:G \longrightarrow P(H) $, $g \mapsto I_g$ a representation?

My first question is: What is $P(H)$? For example, my group is $S_3$ and my subgroup is $H=\{e,(12)\}$, what does $P(H)$ looks like?

After we know how $P(H)$ looks like, how this map works? How can i show that it is (or it is not) a representation?

Comment: Do you mean that $P(H)$ is the group of permutations on $H$ as set?

Comment: Yes, like i said on my example, if i have that $H$, how does $P(H)$ looks?

Comment: I miss why $I_g\in P(H)$.

Comment: Well, me too. This question is in my test and the textbook doesn't help me. I think that we have the following map: $g \mapsto h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$

Comment: If $H$ is finite, then $P(H)\cong S_{|H|}$.

Comment: Ok, but how this help me with the representation proof? I saw some examples and i think that this proposition is true if $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116118/discussion-between-lucas-cantu-and-hal).

Comment: Note that $\forall g\in G, I_g\in P(H) \iff \forall g\in G, \forall h \in H, I_g(h)\in H \iff \forall g\in G, \forall h \in H, ghg^{-1}\in H \iff H\unlhd G$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.